# 2^n - 1 modulo parallel prefix adder

Tags: logic-gates, adder

So I have to do a simple 4-bit modulo 2^n -1 parrallel prefix adder. I've actually made a working one, but not modulo. Now I have a trouble with transforming it to modulo one. This looks like this:

[image]

This is Slenskys PPA. Now I know that this cout has to somehow get back to the beggining of this adder. My lecturer gave me this article, where this schema is presented:

[image]

I know that those diamonds are just simply `XORs`. But now I am really confused. I spent a few hours figuring out what are:

1. Those black dots. I mean are they the same dots as those which appear in PPA structure? If yes (as I suppose) what 2 things go into them? (or pairs of things)
2. This `cout` thing. I know that it is the last wire that is made from that last pair of `AND` and `OR` but then it goes to the beggining and there appears the text `cin`. What does it mean? Does it go with `cin` (I mean `c0`)? Or what?

Comment: are you talking about the black dots at the top and bottom, next to the squares and diamonds?

Comment: Exactly. I mean those at the bottom, above the diamonds

Comment: that just means keep going in the same way. For example, the S2 output diamond would be connected to that dashed line indicated by the dots on the bottom right.

Comment: Okay, but then cout if G or P from a dot, or a wire from OR from AND and OR pair?

Comment: I think they are referring to the large black circles, above the diamonds.